# How do I make the most effective and efficient logic to check the data in the database exist or not?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I use laravel 5.6

I have a json file containing 500 thousand records. I want to create a logic to check whether the id of each record already exists or not in the database. If it doesn't already exist, then there will be a data insert process. If it already exists, there will be a data update process

I have made logic. I just want to make sure whether my logic is effective or not

My logic code like this :

```
$path = storage_path('data.json');
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
foreach ($json['value'] as $value) {
    $data = \DB::table('details')->where('id', '=', $value['Code'])->get();
    if ($data->isEmpty()) {
        \DB::table('details')->insert(
            [
                'id' => $value['Code'],
                'number' => $value['Number'],
                ...
            ]
        );
    }
    else {
        \DB::table('details')
            ->where('id', '=', $value['Code'])
            ->update([
                'id' => $value['Code'],
                'number' => $value['Number'],
                ...
            ]);
    }
}
```

The code is working. But the process seems really long

Do you have another solution that is better?

Comment: you are correct if you were thinking this was inefficient; you are doing 500 select queries when you could potentially just do one.   the inserts could also be done in bulk

Comment: @lagbox I can only do that. I don't know there's another way. So if you have the best solution, please answer this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)**

You may also come across situations where you want to update an existing model or create a new model if none exists. Laravel provides an `updateOrCreate` method to do this in one step. Like the `firstOrCreate` method, `updateOrCreate` persists the model, so there's no need to call  `save()`:

```
// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);
```

---

in your case your code should be like this (create `Details` model first) :

```
$path = storage_path('data.json');
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
foreach ($json['value'] as $value) {
    Details::updateOrCreate(
        [ 'id' => $value['Code'] ],
        [ 'number' => $value['Number'], ... ]
    );
}
```

Comment: update or create still does a select then an insert or update .. it didn't make it any more efficient, its the same amount of queries and the same queries, it just adds a slight overhead of having to go through eloquent now ... though it "looks" cleaner

Comment: @lagbox If you think it's inefficient. What is your solution that is more efficien?

Comment: @Mohsen Safari I want to ask. Can I use `chunk` on the `updateOrCreate`? Because my record is 500 thousand data and it's too long to insert.

Comment: @SuccessMan `updateOrCreate` runs for every json record, so you need to `chunk` your json file but I think `chunk` has no effect on inserting time.

Answer (score 0):

i think that's the best way to do it. Eloquent return's a collection so you cant just validate that your string is null.